# Open file browser using onclick from Material-table actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material table from `"@material-table/core"`

I'm trying to add an action that allows the user to upload a file.

I'm not sure how can I open a file browser when I click on the action icon.

```
actions={[
          {
            icon: 'upload',
            position: "toolbar",
            onClick: (event) => {
                    // TODO - Invokes a file browser for the user to select a file from             
            }
          }
        ]}
```

All the answer I found so far are by using `<input type="file">` but it doesn't apply to my situation.

Comment: Why doesn't using a file input apply to your situation? It is the tool provided for uploading files … which is what you want to do.

Comment: "when I don't already have the input element" — Don't the solutions you've found tell you to add one? ADD ONE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's by `<input type="file">`, if you don't want to show the file input, just give it a `display: none` style for hiding it, and add an id attribute for it, for example `id="file"`, then add a click event listener to your action button,
The click event handler will be for example.

```
const clickHandler = () => {
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
    fileInput.click()
}
```

This will popup the file dialog. ( without showing the file input itself ).